# Appending digits to decimal place in number

Tags: algorithm, numbers

If I want to add a digit to a whole number (`int` in some languages), I can use this (in pseudo-code):

```
num = num * 10
num = num + digit
```

This might result in:

> For `num = 123` and `digit = 4`
>
> This will result in `num = 1234`

But if `num` is a decimal number, how can I add the digit in the decimal place?

> For `num = 0.123` and `digit = 4`
>
> This will result in `num = 0.1234`

What I have so far

```
copy = num
decimalplaces = 0

loop for infinity
{
    decimalplaces = decimalplaces + 1
    copy = copy * 10

    if copy equals floor(copy)
        break out of loop
}

d = d + (digit / pow(10, decimalplaces + 1))
```

But is there a "cleaner" (simpler) way to achieve this (like the adding digit to number function above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation of the decimal number. A string represenation of a base 10 number can be easily appended to and then parsed back into a number. Also, with your method there is no way to add a zero.

```
function appendDecimalDigit(num, digits) {
    return parseFloat(num.toString() + (num.toString().indexOf(".") >= 0 ? digits.toString() : "." + digits.toString()));
}

console.log(appendDecimalDigit(123, "4")); // 123.4
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1234, "5")); // 1234.5
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(123.456, "000789")); // 123.456000789
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1.01, "01")); // 1.0101
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1234567890, "1")); // 1234567890.1
```

If you're intent on a purely numeric solution then you are stuck with something similar to what you already have. **Note: depending on the system you are implementing this on you could run into issues with floating point binary arithmatic (this won't occur with big number decimal math libraries) that will give inaccurate results as the numbers because bigger or more accurate.**

```
function appendDecimalDigit(num, digit) {
    var places = 0;
    while(num * Math.pow(10, places) !== Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, places))) {
        places++;
    }
    return num + digit * Math.pow(10, -(places + 1));
}

console.log(appendDecimalDigit(123, 4)); // 123.4
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1234, 5)); // 1234.5
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(123.456, 9)); // 123.4569
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1.01, 1)); // 1.011
console.log(appendDecimalDigit(1234567890, 1)); // 1234567890.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest storing your decimal number as a pair of integers, with (integer_representation,decimal_places).  This can be modeled as an object type in most modern languages (C++, C#, Java, etc), or as a structure (C, Pascal, etc) to keep it packaged nicely.

In your example of 0.123, your integer representation would be 123, and your decimal_places would be 3.  To add 4, you use the integer approach of multiplying by 10 and adding 4, then increment decimal places.

This approach also avoids the floating point precision problem where the floating point value may not be an exact match, or may not be representable at all, either causing an incorrect result or possibly even an infinite loop.  Conversion to a floating point number is as simple as dividing by pow(10,decimal_places), so there is no chance of an infinite loop with this conversion, and the number is stored precisely so even if it cannot be represented as a floating point, you still have options for implementing comparisons and arithmetic operations.

As an added bonus, languages that support larger integer types than the native CPU register size, such as BigInteger in Java and C#, will allow you to support arbitrary precision floating point numbers in this way, with all of the same ease of appending digits to the end.  Creating a custom big integer type in languages that do not provide existing support would also be fairly easy, since it only requires support for multiplying by 10, adding 0-9, and division by a power of 10.